# How to add custom module content in magento 2.0.7 list.phtml

Tags: custom, magento-2.0.7, fulltext

How to add custom module content in magento 2.0.7  list.phtml

Without modifying core list.phtml i need to append my custom module content in magento 2.0.7 list.phtml

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: ya sure ,in magento 2.0.7  category list page i want to add custom content through my custom module for example i want add custom text above the product image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you create new module to override this block: 
**vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php**

to override this block, you need to create di.xml at , 
**app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\etc**

di.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

Create new file name ListProduct.php at 
**app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product**

ListProduct.php content:

```
namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Vendor_ModuleName::test.phtml')->toHtml();
        $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $html.$renderer->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

You can change block Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template to your block

create yourphtml.phtml file at **app\code\Vendor\Module_Name\view\frontend\templates**

Comment: ok fine thank you for your response ,let me check

Comment: I am getting 
"Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"

My file structure  and type like this 

Type:
Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product

file path :

Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct.php

Comment: yes i got fixed  ,i missed  Catalog in TYPE Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct

Comment: Hi RJ07 Thank you for your answer , i have few more doubts

Its adding content above the add to cart i want to add my custom content into above the category image 

And i want to access helper data(that mean my custom module admin settings like enable disable )  in yourphtml.phtml

Comment: Does it helped you to call your block on list page with above code? yeah please go on.

Comment: Hi RJ07 Thank you for your answer , i have few more doubts

Its adding content above the add to cart i want to add my custom content into above the category image 

And i want to access helper data(that mean my custom module admin settings like enable disable )  in yourphtml.phtml

Comment: To do so first you needs to create admin configurations for enable/disable in system.xml as @Vendorname/Module_Name/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

and after that you can get values of those content. Now to have clear understanding on this you can follow this links which will help you through creating configurations and accessing them. Here is the link @http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/magento2-how-to-get-data-from-system-configuration

Also if you found something in above code you can upvote and accept it. Thanks

Comment: How i can get product id in   yourphtml.phtml

Comment: Add this code to your phtml file,     $_product = $block->getProduct();
$pid = $_product->getId();

Comment: Great!!   RJ07  You Saved my day Thank you so much

Comment: i have another question  Can you please help me

Comment: How we can display product with sale count in my custom module admin grid,I dont know how to create admin Grid in magento 2

Comment: Try this link, http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator .. This will create skeleton of module for you and you can select grid type if you wants to create admin grid as well. Please let me know if it was helpful for you

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you :) It seems you forgot to upvote yet my reply :) would be glad to see your appreciation on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ya sure i do it ( It seems you forgot to upvote yet my reply ) where i need to make upvote

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1386100/c4e88173cd39437fae205c9d2057ba98

Comment: i Completed please check

Comment: Yeah Thanks :) . Link which I gave you helped in creating grid for admin ?

Comment: i am currently working on that ,once complete i will let you know

Comment: ok sure looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: How can i get Custom product  attribute value  in yourphtml.phtml

Comment: I have updated ans here, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125271/how-to-get-attribute-value-in-magento-2-0-6-product-view-and-list-page/125272?noredirect=1#comment169688_125272 . Way is same as I mentioned over there.

Comment: Hi How to submit the magento2 custom module config  form using event observer

Comment: @Rushvi, I am trying to show out of stock products only for specific category, how that can achieved, do i need to override this block file?